# Custom labels on ZedGraph PieChart

Tags: c#, label, zedgraph, pie-chart

I want to create custom labels on my PieChart. Currently, the type of my labels is `PieLabelType.Value` but I need to format the value to display a currency symbol (€) and the thousands separator.

Usually, I use the `String.Format` method with `C0` as an argument, but I can't use `PieLabelType.Value.Format("C0")`.

Code sample:

```
PieItem oTempPie1 = oGraphPane.AddPieSlice(oGerCosts._CNQ_, RedColor, 0, "blabla");
oTempPie1.LabelType = PieLabelType.Value;
PieItem oTempPie2 = oGraphPane.AddPieSlice(oGerCosts._CTQ_, BlueColor, 0, "blabla");
oTempPie2.LabelType = PieLabelType.Value;

oGraphPane.Title.Text = "RDV " + sScenarioReference;
oGraphPane.Legend.Position = LegendPos.Right;
oGraphPane.Legend.IsVisible = true;

// Font:
oGraphPane.Title.FontSpec.Size = c_fDefaultFontSize;
oGraphPane.Title.FontSpec.IsBold = true;
oGraphPane.Legend.FontSpec.Size = c_fDefaultFontSize;
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for my problem.

I've edited the PieItem class of ZedGraph library to add item on the Enum PieLabelType.

I've modified the code to format the return string according to the Enum value.